# Azure DevOps Backlogs: How do you handle sub-features (features within features)?

Tags: azure-devops

Within our software, we want to implement a grid-style "Editor" for filling in information for various components. This Editor is itself a feature, and is expected to do several things out-of-the box. Most of these of these behaviors are simple and work well as Work Items.

However, one feature of the Editor that we want to implement is an auto-fill button for a particular column. This auto-fill feature is fairly involved and will really require multiple work items of its own. So it's essentially a feature within a feature.

However, from what I can tell, DevOps doesn't play very nice with features within features. You can do it, by creating a Work Item under a feature and then converting it to a feature. But then you can't drag to re-order those sub-features like you can sub-Work Items.

So, what's the "proper", best-practice, officially-supported way to handle "features of other features"? Just create the sub-features at the same level as the main feature? This seems very unorganized... but I don't know of a better fully-supported way...

EDIT: To clarify, one of the reasons we'd like to have "sub-Features" at the same level as "sub-Work Items" (in addition to just grouping everything relating to the parent feature together) is so that we can re-order and prioritize sub-Features amid the rest of the sub-Work Items for the parent feature.

Comment: Why don't you use epics to group your features?

Comment: We're using Epics to represent big-picture goals and initiatives. So it wouldn't work well to use them to represent larger software features as well/instead.

Comment: Add an extra backlog level between Epics and Features.

Comment: @DRoam Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Daniel,creating a new backlog level between Epics and Features is a solution.

To do it , first，your project needs to use a inherited process . You can create inherited process in the Process of Boards in Organization Setting.

[image]

Then in the inherited process, you can create a new work item type as a backlog level between Epics and Feature.

[image]